# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' (typescript/Observable/angular2)

Tags: typescript, angular, observable, reactivex

What I want to do is fairly simple, i have a function `getListData` that returns Observable of `Person[]`, and I want to pass that to the html as Person[].

So I did that:

```
 @Injectable()
  export class AppCmp implements OnInit {

    listToDisplay: Person[];

    showingPerson = false;

    constructor(private _myService: MyService) {
    };

    public showMatcherData(): void {
      this.showingPerson = true;
      this. _myService.getListData().subscribe(res => {
        this.listToDisplay = res;
      })
    }
```

but I get an error:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in
>   [listToDisplay in AppCmp@41:60]

this is what I get when I log listToDisplay:

[image]

and this is how im presenting it:

```
<div *ngIf="showingPerson">
    <div dnd-sortable-container  [dropZones]="['zone-one']" [sortableData]="listToDisplay">
      <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#per of listToDisplay; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
        ID: {{per.id}} <p></p> age: {{per.age}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

if im using person2:

```
let person2 = () => {
  return  [
    {
      "id": "2323",
      "age": 22
    },
    {
     "id": "2323",
      "age": 22
    }
    ,
    {
     "id": "2323",
      "age": 22
    }
  ]

};
```

instead of listToDisplay it works, how come?

what does that mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: 1)remove `injectable()` line. 2) make sure `ngOnInit` is implemented 3)if still it doesn't work, show `getListData()` code. 4)`html` could also be problematic.

Comment: I need injectable and ngOnInIt is implemented, I just sent a simplification of my code

Comment: Do you get data in `this.listToDisplay` ? check in console.

Comment: yes bro just added a screen shot of the log @micronyks

Comment: Great also need hTML part how you display your this list of objects.

Comment: added buddy @micronyks

Comment: added some example list to the codethat works @micronyks

Comment: I feel like problem is with `dnd-sortable-xxx`. If you remove this dnd-sortable-xxx libary and just play with `div , ngfor`, i feel like it will work as expected.

Comment: no, see what i added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118699/discussion-between-micronyks-and-joe).

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be related to this `sortableData`:

```
<div dnd-sortable-container  [dropZones]="['zone-one']" [sortableData]="listToDisplay">
```

and not the `*ngFor`.

You should only display the whole thing:

```
<div *ngIf="showingPerson">
```

(That is, change the flag that is at the `*ngIf`) **after** you load the data, not before like you are right now.

So this:

```
public showMatcherData(): void {
  this.showingPerson = true;   // <------------------------------ line will move
  this. _myService.getListData().subscribe(res => {
    this.listToDisplay = res;
  })
}
```

Should become:

```
public showMatcherData(): void {
  this. _myService.getListData().subscribe(res => {
    this.listToDisplay = res;
    this.showingPerson = true; // <------------------------------ line moved
  })
}
```